# How to handle territory conflicts in Part Time Gods Second Edition?

Tags: part-time-gods

I'm going to start my first campaign, but I have some concerns regarding the territory and grid system. It seems like an exciting part of the game to have conflicts with other pantheons over territory, but it feels like the system isn't supporting it much.
Here are my main concerns.:

- Grid is too small: There are only 81 territory boxes, an attachment claim on average of 3.24 boxes when you talk into account corners and edges. I found that most characters have around 3 attachments giving territory (Looking at the ones in the book and the result when I created a bunch of NPCs and my players made their PCs). If they are evenly spread, this only leaves room for 8 NPC/PC to have territory without overlap. Which it naturally will not. This seems like it will result in lots of conflicts over territory.
- Challenge ritual: This is the only system-supported way I have found that territory can be claimed from someone without killing them. This ritual costs 2 free time and 2 fragments to do, and if I understand it correctly can be interrupted by a bolster ritual. Forcing you to do it again and, I assume, pay the cost again. 4 fragments would, as I understand, lower, either require you to lose one spark or do the second round of the ritual the next session.
- Clash of Dominion: The Admittance ritual says that you initiate a clash of dominion if you enter another territory without performing this ritual. However, I can't find any rules about what this mean.

I'm looking for your table experience using the system regarding the territory. Have I missed something or misunderstood something that removes the problem? Or did you implement house rules to get around these problems? Or did you not experience them at all?

As a bonus question, I got Divine Instrument from the first edition. It has a different take on the territory. Are there any conversion rules to use this with the second edition? I haven't read any first-edition rules besides Divine Instrument.